# How to avoid login logging?

Tags: debian, shell, ssh, logs, authentication

I'm wondering how can one login to a server without being easily traceable. I've already read [here](https://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html) that one can avoid `last/wtmp` by using /bin/sh shell. I was wondering if it was possible to even avoid auth.log or pam.

Comment: Will `ssh server /bin/sh` do what you want? (that will start an interactive `sh` session, which may not have a prompt on some systems)

Comment: Or `chsh` perhaps... But `/bin/sh` on Debian is either Bash, or `dash`, and the latter isn’t suitable for interactive use really; so why do you want to change?

Comment: @StephenKitt because I've read that it will not run any login script. Also, this kind of login does not appear in last/wtmp so I won't be easily tracked.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Why delete it? Please undelete since it seems like a valuable addition to the site.

Comment: @terdon because I already knew the answer! I already had tried what Kusalananda said and just didn't realized that I was already in the system since no msgs were shown. So I thought it was a useless question. Don't you think I should delete it!?

Comment: Oh, um, actually what I found interesting was the fact that this login isn't stored in wtmp but I hadn't realized that that wasn't really the point of your question. Sorry! So up to you. Feel free to delete and feel free to post an answer with the solution you ended up using.

Comment: @terdon check out https://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html ;) Can you check out my new question!? I'm stuck with it for a long time!:(

Comment: @Kusalananda Can you post the answer please!? would you be so kind to mention this type of login won't show any output and the login can be verified using ls or smth of that sort?

Comment: Now I'm not sure what the point of the question is, changing the shell or avoiding the `wtmp` logging? The latter would be somewhat interesting as a question, but it's not in the question proper...

Comment: so @aran, if the non logging is the point, can you [edit] that as the main point of the question?

Comment: @ilkkachu sure, that's a good idea:)

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` will run the given command instead of the login shell:

```
$ ssh server /bin/sh
```

Note that this will start an interactive `sh` session that *may not have a prompt*.  Even if it does not have a prompt, it will still accept commands as any other interactive shell, and you may use `PS1='$ '` to enable a simple primary prompt.